# How can I replace an unknown number of words in a string with values contained in an array?

Tags: string, vb.net

Given a string how can i replace the words that begin with "#" by the contents in array sequentially.

Ex.

```
dim s as string = "select * from tb where p1 = #p1 and p2 = #p2"
dim param() as string = {"value1", "value2"}
```

I'm looking for:

```
dim result = "select * from tb where p1 = value1 and p2 = value2"
```

I'm try something like that but it doesn't work

```
            Dim paramIndex As Integer = 0
            Dim m() As String
                m = Query.Split(" ")
            For Each ma In m
                If ma.IndexOf("#") >= 0 Then
                    ma = "'" & param(paramIndex) & "'"
                    paramIndex += 1
                End If
            Next
            Query = String.Join(" ", m)
```

I've found some similar questions but none for vb.net

Comment: dont!!...use query string parameters to run your queries

Comment: [String.Format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format) supports an array of parameters. But, as already noted, [xxxCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters) is your friend.

Comment: You would do best to follow the recommendations of @Ctznkane525 and @Jimi. However, the reason your code is not working is that you are not doing anything to change the `m` array, the `ma` strings that you are changing are just copies of the values in the `m` array.

Comment: I simplified my answer, removing the general case so only your specific case is left. It should be clear how simple it is now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This function uses a regular expression to find all words beginning with `#`, then loops through and replaces them with your array values:

```
Private Function replaceSubStrings(input As String, params As String()) As String
    Dim pattern = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex($"#\w+")
    Dim matches = pattern.Matches(input)
    Dim output = input
    For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        output = output.Replace(matches(i).Value, params(i))
    Next
    Return output
End Function
```

This is how it is used:

```
Dim input = "select * from tb where p1 = #p1 and p2 = #p2"
Dim param = {"value1", "value2"}
Dim result = replaceSubStrings(input, param)
```

result:

> select * from tb where p1 = value1 and p2 = value2